# NoMethodError: undefined method `check_url' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, webdriver, watir

I have a module which i have included into my main class:

```
module GenericPage

  def check_url=(page)
    puts(page)
  end

end
```

I create a new instance of my class, which I am calling in Cucumber

```
require_relative '../../../support/helper_methods'


class FindYourDealerPage
  include GenericPage


  def initialize(browser)
    @browser = browser
  end

def search_location=(location)
  @browser.text_field(:id, 'findDealerSearchField').set(location)
  @browser.send_keys :tab, :enter
end
```

Cucumber:

```
    Given /^I am on the find your dealer page$/ do

    @browser.goto 'www.google.com'
    @dealer.check_url('www.google.com')
    @dealer = FindYourDealerPage.new(@browser)
    end

    When /^I select a desired preference$/ do

    end

    Then /^my filtered selection should be submitted$/ do

    end
```

When this is run I get an error `NoMethodError: undefined method`check_url' for nil:NilClass` where am I going wrong, forget what is in the method for the moment I just would like to know why I receive this error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem, I think, is here

```
@dealer.check_url('www.google.com')
@dealer = FindYourDealerPage.new(@browser)
```

Notice how you call `check_url` before you assign `@dealer`... meaning that `@dealer` is still `nil` when you make the method call, and that's why you get a `NoMethodError` for `nil:NilClass`.

Also, you currently have `def check_url=(page)`, but you call `check_url(page)`. Depending on what you mean to happen here, you need to change the definition to `def check_url(page)` or change the call to `@dealer.check_url = 'www.google.com'` (I suspect the former is more appropriate).